# Visual Studio 2010 HTML Designer Renders Unlike IE8?

Tags: html, css, visual-studio

My question is: since Visual Studio 2010 was only just released, why does it not render pages in the same way as the latest Microsoft web browser, IE8?

Is there a bunch of render options I should be setting?

I thought Expression Web was supposed to help with its fancy Super Preview but that app doesn't even open VS solutions.

Thanks for any assistance, Luke

Comment: Anything *not* rendering like IE should be praised not questioned  :)

Comment: :) you're right (ie8's not so bad to be fair) but I can't understand how every change has to be ran and tested in continuous trial and error. Is this how the web was built? Its horrific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay Scott Guthrie says that it uses it's own renderer and that they're looking at ways to allow more live editing with true WYSIWYG.

I think I'll do full HTML mockups in Expression Web and then try and chop over the chunks of HTML into my MVC 2 project and master pages. Maybe its my process of building sites which is suboptimal.

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia states that VS uses trident (IE's render engine) up to VS2005. I can't find what it uses nowadays anywhere, though. It's probably not IE based.

Comment: Hmm.. I'm surprised that this question wasn't quashed in minutes of it going up. I'll email Scott Guthrie and find out.